# postgres jsonb, query an array of objects

Tags: postgresql

i've a jsonb field containing json from [iiif](https://iiif.io) manifests.
i'm interested in extracting the `metadata` block, is an array of json objects in the form

`{label:"', value:""}`

example:

```
"metadata": [
    {
        "label": "Homepage",
        "value": "<span><a href=\"https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/inquire/p/1bac4a1e-fba6-4466-baf5-ef2d45a47ec1\">View on Digital Bodleian</a></span>"
    },
    {
        "label": "Creator",
        "value": "Exeter-'Change (London, England) [author]"
    },
    {
        "label": "Contributors",
        "value": "Incledon, Charles Benjamin, 1763-1826 [performer]"
    },
    {
        "label": "Date Statement",
        "value": "1781-11-24"
    }
]
```

i would like a query to have columns named as `label` with the relative `value`, for all objects of `metadata[]`, as example:

```
|Creator                                    |Contributors                                     |
|-------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|Exeter-'Change (London, England) [author]  |Incledon, Charles Benjamin, 1763-1826 [performer]|
```

is this a trivial query to compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be trivial [or not].

If you know every label from metadata (perhaps because you extracted them earlier) then you can use the pivot table function of postgresql:

First you need to enable the function:

```
CREATE extension tablefunc;
```

then you can use crosstab like that:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab ('
    SELECT t.id as id, m->>''label'', m->>''value'' 
        FROM import.manifest t, 
             LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.data->''metadata'') m 
        ORDER BY 1,2
    ', '
        select distinct m->>''label'' 
            FROM import.manifest t, 
                 LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.data->''metadata'') m 
            order by 1
    ') AS ct (id int,Author text, Contributors text, Creator text, "Date Statement" text, Homepage text, Published text);
```

You have to put all your label in the query it is why it is not so trivial.

The crosstab function take 2 parameters:

- first one is the SQL that return 3 column:

  - One ID column to join data
  - key column. Text from this column will be the name of a column in the result
  - value column
- Second one, is a SQL that return all columns you will have.

With the function, you also need to define the result you will have. It means the `as ct(....)` is mandatory. 
it must reference the id column and all the column you will have for return. for your use case, it is the return of:

```
select distinct(m->>'label') 
    FROM manifest t, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'metadata') m 
    order by 1
```

Comment: my json are in the `import` schema, `manifest` table.  
i tried this query:  


`        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            crosstab ('SELECT m->>''label'', m->>''value''
                                FROM import.manifest t,
                                    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.data->''metadata'') m
                                ORDER BY 1,2') AS ct (Creator TEXT);`

but i got this error: `ERROR: pq: invalid source data SQL statement`

Comment: I explain a little bit more the request. You need to return 3 column in the inside SQL. (id, column name, column value)